# Infinite while loop issue while inserting element to quadtree

Tags: java, quadtree

I'm trying to insert element to quadtree when mouse clicked. I call insert method when mouse clicked and sending point as parameter. After few clicks, while loop in insert method goes infinity and I couldn't find out why.

Here's method;

```
public void insert(Point point){
        Node newNode = new Node(point);
        if(root==null){
            root=newNode;
            return;
        }
        Node current=root;
        Node parent=null;

        while(true){
            parent = current;
            System.out.println("a");
            if(point.getX()<current.point.getX() && point.getY()<current.point.getY()){
                current=current.NW;
                if(current==null){
                    parent.NW= newNode;
                    return;
                }           
            }
            else if(point.getX()>current.point.getX() && point.getY()<current.point.getY()){
                current=current.NE;
                if(current==null){
                    parent.NE= newNode;
                    return;
                }           
        }
            else if(point.getX()<current.point.getX() && point.getY()>current.point.getY()){
                current=current.SW;
                if(current==null){
                    parent.SW=newNode;
                    return;
                }
            }
            else if(point.getX()>current.point.getX() && point.getY()>current.point.getY()){
                current=current.SE;
                if(current==null){
                    parent.SE=newNode;
                    return;
                }
            }

    }
    }
```

If you need rest of code, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you haven't covered the cases where `point` and `current.point` are the same point, or are in line horizontally, or are in line vertically.  In each of these three cases, none of your `if` conditions are true, and there's no way to exit the loop.

You need to change either your `<` conditions to `<=` or your `>` conditions to `>=`.  So, something like

```
if(point.getX()<=current.point.getX() && point.getY()<=current.point.getY()){
```

and similarly for every other comparison you've done using `<`.

This makes sure that your loop can exit when the X value are equal, or when the Y values are equal.